# How to handle Extraction of two zip files in same folder which contain files with same name

Tags: shell-script, filenames, zip

I am using `for` loop for unzipping multiple files:

```
ls *.zip | for zipfile in *.zip;
do
    unzip "$zipfile"
done
```

If while unzipping two zip files, there is a file with same name in both zip then I want to concatenate those both files into single file with same name in same folder.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no directories in the archive:

```
GLOBIGNORE=.:..
mkdir tmpdir1 tmpdir2 targetdir
unzip -d tmpdir1 "$zipfile1"
unzip -d tmpdir2 "$zipfile2"
cd tmpdir1
for file in *; do
    if [ -f "../tmpdir2/${file}" ]; then
        cat "$file" "../tmpdir2/${file}" >"../targetdir/${file}"
    else
        mv $file" "../targetdir/"
    fi
done
cd ../tmpdir2
mv * targetdir/
```

Comment: Is there any way to set a condition like if file with same name found then concatenate it or else leave it as is? As I have multiple zip files and this problem is only for some of them, the way you told is difficult to implement